# Blind SQL injection in end--fields

Tags: mysql, sql, code-injection

I have used this blind SQL injection in `ORDER BY` clause:

```
(CASE WHEN 1 THEN col1 ELSE col2 END)
```

It would produce a query like this:

```
SELECT x FROM y ORDER BY (CASE WHEN 1 THEN col1 ELSE col2 END) ASC
```

This injection was successful and I have white listed all column names in ORDER BY clause.

I was unable to use similar injection in other end-fields. It left me wondering if it is possible and if there should be white listing for those fields, too.

I have tried this kind of injections but have not been successful:

```
SELECT x FROM y ORDER BY col1 (CASE WHEN 1 THEN DESC ELSE ASC END)
SELECT x FROM y ORDER BY col1 DESC LIMIT (CASE WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0
SELECT x FROM y ORDER BY col1 DESC LIMIT 0, CAST((CASE WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SIGNED)
```

Maybe I should white list or enumerate the `DESC/ASC` field and `LIMIT` variables, just for safety? I'm using MySQL. Maybe these injections would be possible on some other DBMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be answered by looking at the [`SELECT` syntax definition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html). The `ORDER BY` clause is defined as:

```
ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position} [ASC | DESC], ...
```

The `(CASE WHEN 1 THEN col1 ELSE col2 END)` in your first example works because it’s an [expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/expressions.html). However, `DESC` and `ASC` are not part of the expression but fixed tokens.

Similar to that, the `LIMIT` clause is defined as:

```
LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}
```

Again, *offset* and *row_count* are not expressions either but only numbers:

> `LIMIT` takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants […]